k8s - prevent garbage collection of local images
Air-gapped k8s cluster 1.27, CRI is containerd. Container's images are uploaded to nodes via ssh and imported with "crt image import". The nodes are physical devices with pretty low storage capacity. The issue is that garbage collection deletes images upon HighThresholdPercent. So once pod restarted it fails on ImagePull. Is there the way to prevent GC to delete 'unused' images? Should be something straightforward by seems I miss the point.
The obvious way to manage a local repo doesn't seem an option due low resource capacity of the cluster.
